# saving a text in the notepad in android

Tags: java, android

I just want to ask about my code whether it's right, because I can't load the text in my `name.txt` file.
Also I just want to know how to save the input text in my `name.txt` file.

```
load.setOnClickListener(new 

View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick

(View arg0) {
            try{


StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();


FileInputStream fis=con.openFileInput("name.txt");


DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(fis);


String text=null;


while((text=dis.readLine())!=null)


sb.append(text+"\n");


dis.close();


et1.setText(sb.toString()); 

            }catch 

(IOException e){


Toast.makeText(con, "Could not find", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write data to file

```
static protected void writeToFile(String strToWrite)
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("name.txt", true));
        out.write(strToWrite);
        out.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

The code you have written is to read data from an existing file not to write in the file.

Comment: do i really have to create that method?

Comment: what i did is..

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
      try{
         BufferedWriter out= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("raw/name.txt",true));
         mystr=et1.getText().toString();
         out.write(mystr);
         out.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
       }
      });

but still nothing happen to my name.txt file.

Comment: No it is not necessary to have function, have you tried by hard coding the string just to test the code ? It might happen that there is no text to write to file (Just check).

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
    File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dir/", "filename.extension");
    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
    bw1.write("Stringtowritetofile");
    bw1.close();
}
```